# How to know if scrollbar is at the bottom of an element

Tags: elm, onscroll

Is there any way to know if a scrollbar is at the bottom of an element in Elm? I'm using `Dom.Scroll.toBottom` to scroll to the bottom of a list when a list item is added. That works great when leaving it alone. But if you manually scroll up a little, I don't want to auto-scroll down to the bottom anymore (until you manually scroll to the bottom again). Otherwise you can't review the previous list items.

Comment: Is there any problem that doesn't allow using [`Dom.Scroll.y`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/dom/1.1.1/Dom-Scroll#y)?

Comment: @lonelyelk `Dom.Scroll.y` is not sufficient to know if the scrollbar is at the bottom of an element. `y` only tells you how far down (in pixels) the scroll is. Without knowing how far the **bottom** is, how would you know you're at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the `clientHeight`, `scrollHeight`, and `scrollTop` properties with the following code. Those were necessary to know whether the scroll is at the bottom of an element. The rest of the code implements the mechanism for auto-scrolling only if scroll is already at bottom:

```elm
type alias Model =
    { messages : List Message
    , autoScrollMessages : Bool
    }

type Msg
    = NoOp (Result Dom.Error ())
    | ReceiveMessage ReceivedMessage
    | ScrolledMessages ScrollEvent

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        NoOp res ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
        ReceiveMessage message ->
            ( { model | messages = model.messages ++ [ message ] } , if model.autoScrollMessages then Task.attempt NoOp (Scroll.toBottom "messages") else Cmd.none )
        ScrolledMessages scrollEvent ->
            ( { model | autoScrollMessages = scrollEvent.scrollPos == scrollEvent.scrollHeight - scrollEvent.visibleHeight }, Cmd.none )

type alias ScrollEvent =
  { scrollHeight : Int
  , scrollPos : Int
  , visibleHeight : Int
  }

onScroll : (ScrollEvent -> msg) -> Html.Attribute msg
onScroll tagger =
  Html.Events.on "scroll" (Decode.map tagger onScrollJsonParser)

onScrollJsonParser : Decode.Decoder ScrollEvent
onScrollJsonParser =
  Decode.map3 ScrollEvent
      (Decode.at ["target", "scrollHeight"] Decode.int)
      (Decode.at ["target", "scrollTop"] Decode.int)
      (Decode.at ["target", "clientHeight"] Decode.int)

viewMessages : List Message -> Html Msg
viewMessages messages =
    ul
        [ id "messages"
        , onScroll ScrolledMessages
        ] <| List.map viewMessage messages
```